# Discord.py how to add a countdown to an embed

Tags: discord.py

I have been trying to find a way to add a countdown in an embed but can't find anything. So when current_time reaches a certain time, it sends an embed and starts counting down in one of the fields.

````
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(auth)

    while not client.is_closed():
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(current_time)

if current_time == "03:09:00":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                colour = discord.Colour.green(),
                title = "test"
            )
            embed.set_image(url = "(img)") #
            embed.set_thumbnail(url = "(img)") #
            **embed.add_field(name="Timer", value ="??:??:??", inline = True) #Timer goes at ??:??:??                                                                                                                       
            embed.add_field(name="Location", value ="adding later", inline = True) 

            await channel.send(embed=embed)
client.loop.create_task(background_task())```
````

Comment: Try looking into `Embed.timestamp`. It is what is responsible for messages with footer timestamps like `Yesterday at 3pm`. As for editing the embed, you can look into task schedulers and edit the embed.

Answer (score 0):

Since its all in a `async` function, you could do something like this

```py
@client.command()
async def countdown(ctx, *args):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title='foo',
        description='bar'
    )
    now = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    embed.insert_field_at(
        index=0,
        name='countdown',
        value=str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
    )
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    while datetime.datetime.now() < now:
        embed.remove_field(index=0)
        embed.insert_field_at(
            index=0,
            name='countdown',
            value=str(now-datetime.datetime.now())
        )
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        asyncio.sleep(5)
```